# OLEDB ACQUIRE CONNECTION ERROR SSIS

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

Hi I am getting this error in my SSIS packages on alternate days

An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is available.The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "" failed with error code 0xC0202009.

Symbolic Name: DTS_E_OLEDBERROR The hexadecimal value for this error number = 0x80004005.

I found the solution in Microsoft site

To resolve this issue, you must change the permissions for the Temp directory of the SQL Server Agent Service startup account. Grant the Read permission and the Write permission to the SQL Server 2005 Agent proxy account for this directory.

But where do i find TEMP directory for Sql Server agent Service start-up account in my system . Since I could not locate it in my system . plz help me how to go ahead with that change.

Thanks mushtaq

Answer (score 0):

I believe the temp directory is here:

```
c:\Documents and Settings\<Account>\Local Settings\Temp
```

Comment: I got it but when i checked the permission it is already have Read/Write permission for TEMP FOLDER. Actually i was referring solution for my query from the this link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/933835 from microsoft.